# How to tell if an existing java.util.Date matches a particular format

Tags: java, date, formatting

I am being passed a `java.util.Date` instance and need to make sure it conforms to a `MM/dd/YYYY` format. How can I perform such validation (sans libraries like Joda Time)? I checked the API methods for `SimpleDateFormat` but nothing is cropping up a clear winner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I were you I would be using `java.util.Calendar`, `java.util.Date` is deprecated as of JDK version 1.1.

Comment: @Abaab `java.util.Date` is not deprecated at all, some methods/constructors are but the class itself is not deprecated and used by a lot of APIs / frameworks.

Comment: @Abaab `Date` itself is not deprecated. Most methods are, thanks to `Calendar`, but not the class itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.util.Date` encapsulates the number of milliseconds since the epoch. It does not have the notion of a format. Therefore input validation for `Date` has no meaning - this only applys to a `String` representation of `Date`.

Answer (score 4):

the `java.util.Date` itself has no format - just an internal `long` representation of the milliseconds since 1.1.1970 01:00

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it will work for you,

```
    String s = "2013-05-07";
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(s);
        System.out.println(date+" Format of date recognized");

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("unable to recognize the date format");
    }
```

This code will work perfectly, only the String in the format yyyy/MM/dd would work rest all would throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
ft.setLenient(false); // This will result in a ParseException when an invalid day and/or month
System.out.println(ft.format(ft.parse(s)));
```